# Minimizing the variance covariance matrix

Tags: optimization, covariance

I need to understand why we are taking the $\frac{1}{2}$ fraction when i want to minimize the variance covariance matrix:

$\min _{\omega} \frac{1}{2} \omega^{\top} \mathbf{V} \omega$.

Our professor is going on to using the Lagrangian to minimize the matrix, I dont know if this has something to do with the $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Imagine you want to minimize $f(x)=x^2$. You have $f'(x)=2x$. That $2$ can be annoying. If you had $f(x)=\tfrac12 x^2$, you would have gotten $f'(x)=x$ instead. Same here, that $1/2$ just removes some factors of 2 which appear by differentiation.

Comment: Ah, genious! Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome.